# Sublime Text 2 Build Command Does Nothing For LaTeX

Tags: pdf

I've been using Sublime Text 2 and Sumatra PDF to build and view the Master's thesis I've been writing in LaTeX. Last night I was working in Sublime on the document with no issues. Today, I get to work and have a moment to work on my thesis so I open Sublime and attempt to ctrl+B to build my document and nothing happens; nothing in the status bar, no errors. It's as if the ctrl+B was never implemented to do anything. I then went to tools-->Build and the same issue. I switched the Build System in the Tools menu to Python and attempted to build and I did get errors in the status bar (just wanted to see if something was frozen or whatnot). I switched back to LaTeX in Build Systems, try to build and nothing. I'm not new to LaTeX or Sublime however, I have no idea where to start on troubleshooting this problem. Does anyone have any ideas/dealt with this before?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I deleted all of the files associated with the generation of my PDF, closed Sublime and then re-opened it and the package control manager displayed installing a new plugin once Sublime was back on the screen. I proceeded to tools-->Build and everything worked fine. I'm not sure if deleting the files fixed the issue or if the installation of the plugin didbut I'm glad it's working again; I want to graduate lol!